# Maven Android SDK Deployer run the command "mvn install" error: Properties file not found

Tags: android, maven

Maven Android SDK Deployer run the command "mvn install" error:

> Properties file not found

Please tell me why? How to fix the error? For example error:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:read-project-properties (default) on project google-apis-4:
>   Properties file
>    not found: D:\ICSEclipse\android-sdk-windows\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-4
>   \source.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is addressed right in the install instructions: https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer#known-problems

In short, if you have and ADK that has been downloaded a long time ago and then updated you need to delete it completely and redownload it. The issue is a number of folder name changes  between updates and the fact that de deployer only works with the newest naming scheme.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't help for me, since I just downloaded both the latest ADK and latest sdk-deployer and still got the error, without having any old versions.

I got it to work when I resolved these:

1. The first problem was that I didn't install all the platforms and extras after installing the ADK. That needs to be done using the SDK manager.
2. After that two of the modules failed, so they had to be commented out like explained in [this pull request](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer/pull/196).
3. Then it failed for me with javadoc error. This was due to JDK 8, which apparently is not yet supported, for which I opened [this issue](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer/issues/197). With JDK 7 it worked.